# How to suppress warning of private API?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad

I am trying to use a private animation (since I am not submitting it to App Store)

```
 [UIView setAnimationTransition:103 forView:detailVC.view cache:YES];
 [UIView setAnimationPosition: CGPointMake(262, 723)];
```

I get two warnings from `setAnimationPosition`.

> 1. "UIView may not respond to setAnimationPosition"
> 2. "Semantic Issue, method setAnimationPosition not found".

Is there anyway to suppress these two warnings?

Thanks

Leo

Answer (score 4):

Simply declare them in a category declaration, like follows:

```
@interface UIView (PrivateMethods)
+ (void)setAnimationPosition:(CGPoint)point;
@end
```

However, as noted by Martin Gordon, Apple will reject your app if it uses private APIs.

Comment: I tried that, but the warning is still on. I added the code before my @implementation, I am not sure if it's working

Comment: Change the - to a + since it's a class method.

Comment: I realized the setAnimationPosition is actually a class method. So by replacing "-" with "+" in your code, the warning is gone. I'll accept your answer if you fix it. Thanks!

Comment: Oops, should've noticed that small bit :)  Looks like someone else just fixed it for me.  Thanks, Jeremy.

Answer (score 2):

A good development practice is to treat warnings as errors (unless you have a **really** good reason not to).

In your case, use of private APIs should be considered an error because Apple will reject your app if it uses undocumented APIs.

Comment: Yes. I do intend to treat warnings as errors, that's why I want to suppress this warning because I am not planning to submit my app to Apple..

Comment: Note for future voters: OP is NOT intending to submit to the App Store, so this is not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add **-w** Complier Flag under *Build Phases > Compile Sources* against *yourfilename.m*

Note : *this is working for non-arc class.*